# Partial or override configuration options in asp.net core appsettings?

Tags: configuration, .net-core

I'd like to have a default setting section and several override sections in appsetting.json where I only need to override certain fields of a subsection but "inherit" default settings. Is there built in support for such behaviour?

For example Override1 gets the default settings for settings 1, 3 & 4 but has its own setting for setting2.

```
{
  "SectionOfSimilarTypes": {
    "DefaultSettings" : {
      "setting1": "default1",
      "setting2": "default2",
      "setting3": "default3",
      "setting4": "default4"
    },
    "Override1" : {
      "setting2": "somethingelse"
     }
   }
}
```